# LaTeX (Context) document size over 226in

Tags: size, latex, limit, document

I've been looking left, right and center but was not able to find a definitive answer as to how and whether it is possible to increase document size in LaTeX over the magic 200inch limit.

For a project I work on I need to be able to dynamically generate PDF/EPS that can be used to print on up to 32 yards long medium. The important factor is, that this print job must be seamless and contains color stripes, symbols and texts on repeat throughout the entire length.

I know that PDF 1.6+ supports a much larger document size via setting UserUnits. Is that something that can be used in LaTeX and if so, how would I go about this?

Comment: Try asking at tex.stackexchange.com, probably better luck there.